# "Cannot resolve symbol" error for ScanAPI / Android

Tags: java, android

I’m developing on Windows 10 using Android Studio 2.2. The app is for a smartphone. I just downloaded the SDK for ScanAPI. I've created a directory 'libs' and copied the JAR files for SCANAPI. My import statement gives me a "Cannot resolve symbol" error. Here's the statement
 **import com.socketmobile.scanapi.ISktScanDevice**
It doesn’t like the socketmobile part of the statement.
The example project “singleEntry” doesn’t have this issue.

build.gradle entry:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

Comment: *I'm developing on Android* on? Not for? Where is at least dependency part of build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

The "libs" directory was not in the module that was referencing the library. Therefore the dependencies were not getting included.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',     {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
```

})